# What is the point of the third parameter in SetPixelFormat() for OpenGL context creation?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, opengl

Before creating an OpenGL context on Windows, we need to call `SetPixelFormat` for the Window's device context. Its function prototype is as follows:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetPixelFormat(
     HDC hdc,
     int iPixelFormat,
     const PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR *ppfd);
```

When creating a fixed function context, we get a supported pixel format index by calling `ChoosePixelFormat` with our desired pixel format, so the value that really matters is the value passed as the `iPixelFormat` argument. And when creating a modern GL context, we still need to call `SetPixelFormat` [according to the docs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL))

> "Once you have a pixel format number, you can set it just like any pixel format with `SetPixelFormat`."

This is even though the `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` structure is not really relevant. In this case, I've just been passing `NULL`.

Does it matter what I pass as the third parameter to `SetPixelFormat`? If so, when?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well yes and no. The PFD struct is mainly used for `ChoosePixelFormat`, unless you're using `wglChoosePixelFormatARB` of course. As far as I recall `SetPixelFormat` relies on `iPixelFormat` and passing the PFD struct is just a nice "extra" or meta data in other words.

The [`SetPixelFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd369049(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation is a bit cryptic but does actually mention this:

> Pointer to a [`PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368826(v=vs.85).aspx) structure that contains the logical pixel format specification. The system's metafile component uses this structure to record the logical pixel format specification. The structure has no other effect upon the behavior of the [`SetPixelFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd369049(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

So first you setup a PFD and define what your pixel format requires. Then calling `ChoosePixelFormat` finds a matching pixel format and returns the index. Calling `SetPixelFormat` then applies this pixel format using the index to the device context. The PFD in relation to `SetPixelFormat` is just meta data.

All in all I would recommend passing it anyways, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: That's what I do for Fixed Function OpenGL context creation, where I first copy the values of the chosen index using `DescribePixelFormat`. But what about the case for modern OpenGL context creation, where the pixel format is chosen using `wglChoosePixelFormatARB`, and the PFD structure is not even used? Any idea?

Comment: Take a look at my edit, it reflects this.